# Deleteing a youtube video using PHP, a Video ID, and API Key

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to delete a youtube video using API V3 with just the Video id and Key? I keep getting an error about a "Required parameter: part" missing. I tried it with the Server and Browser api key Here is my code:

```
// $youtube_id = the ID string and $key = the Key for browser applications
$delete_string = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" .  $youtube_id ."&key=" . $key;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$delete_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch)
```

I get the error:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Required parameter: part", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "part" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Required parameter: part" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing the HTTP Verb, maybe this causes this error too.

Try adding this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
```

By the way, maybe you'll want to use a php api for that like [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), so you don't have to reinvent everything.